Dealing with Chunk file upload using jQuery and ASP.NET MVC
I am trying to upload the documents in a bulk as a chunk but unfortunately the documents which are being uploaded is corrupted.
I am storing few metadata along with file, first I am storing the information in JSON and the JSON will be stored on server and after that based on the JSON folder will get created with all the files inside the folder, then I am running one service to store the document in our system from the hard folder, while storing the files in a hard folder on server using chunk I am facing this issue
This is my code:
function btnUpload_click() {
    var e = filename[0];
    !e ? Utils.showAlert("File input element not found.")
        : e.files.length === 0 ? Utils.showAlert("Files not selected for upload.")
            : (messagediv.html(''), multipleFileUpload(e));
}
function multipleFileUpload(e) {
    const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024; // 1MB chunk size
    var SaveDetails = {
        DocTypeId: ctrlDocType.data("kendoDropDownList").value(),
        ProcessId: ctrlProcess.data("kendoDropDownList").value(),
        ClassificationLevel: ctrlClassificationLevel.data("kendoDropDownList").value(),
        Priority: ctrlPriority.data("kendoDropDownList").value(),
        FolderId: FolderId,
        TreatFileNameAsDocumentNumber: $('#chkTreatAsDocNumber').is(':checked') ? 'Y' : 'N',
        LoggedInUserId: Utils.getUserId(),
        FileUploadItemList: [],
        MetaDataDateFormat: ___culture,
    };
    debugger
    saveBulkUploadWithMetaDataJSON(SaveDetails, function (data) {
        debugger
        var promises = [];
        SaveDetails.Id = data.Ref1;
        for (var i = 0; i < e.files.length; i++) {
            var file = e.files[i];
            promises.push(readFileInChunks(file, chunkSize, SaveDetails));
        }
        Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
            clearDropDownOnChange('');
            GetAllServiceFilesForBulkUploadWithMetaData();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            Utils.showError(error.message);
        });
    });
}
function readFileInChunks(file, chunkSize, saveDetails) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        let offset = 0;
        const chunks = [];

        reader.onload = function (event) {
            const base64Data = event.target.result.split(',')[1]; // Extract base64 data
            const fileItem = {
                FileName: file.name,
                FileContent: base64Data
            };
            saveDetails.FileUploadItemList = [];
            saveDetails.FileUploadItemList.push(fileItem);

            // Update the offset and read the next chunk
            offset += chunkSize;
            debugger
            if (offset < file.size) {
                saveDetails.FileUploadItemList[0].ChunkUploaded = false;
                // Call the update function for each chunk
                UpdateFileChunkBulkUploadWithMetaDataJSON(saveDetails)
                    .then(readNextChunk)
                    .catch(reject); // Handle any errors during the update
            } else {
                saveDetails.FileUploadItemList[0].ChunkUploaded = true;
                // Resolve the promise with the collected chunks
                UpdateFileChunkBulkUploadWithMetaDataJSON(saveDetails)
                    .then(() => resolve(chunks))
                    .catch(reject); // Handle any errors during the final update
            }
        };

        reader.onerror = function (event) {
            reject(new Error("File could not be read! Code " + event.target.error.code));
        };

        function readNextChunk() {
            const blob = file.slice(offset, offset + chunkSize);
            reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
        }

        readNextChunk();
    });
}
function saveBulkUploadWithMetaDataJSON(SaveDetails, callback) {
    ajaxCallFunction("POST", "/api/BulkUpload/BulkUpload/BulkUploadWithMetaDataJSON", JSON.stringify(SaveDetails), function (response) {
        callback != undefined ? callback(response) : '';
    });
}
function UpdateFileChunkBulkUploadWithMetaDataJSON(saveDetails) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        ajaxCallFunction("POST", "/api/BulkUpload/BulkUpload/UpdateFileChunkBulkUploadWithMetaDataJSON", JSON.stringify(saveDetails), function (response) {
            if (response.ReturnStatus == "0") {
                resolve(response);
            } else {
                reject(new Error("Failed to update chunk metadata"));
            }
        });
    });
}

Here is my API:
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[Filters.AuthorizeLoginApi()]
[Route("api/BulkUpload/BulkUpload/BulkUploadWithMetaDataJSON")]
[RateLimitApiAttribute(count: GetCountOnFunctions.AddEdit, timeUnit: GetMinutesOnFunctions.AddEdit)]
public CSVUploadResponse BulkUploadWithMetaDataJSON([FromBody] DocPro.DMS.BusinessEntities.Request.BulkUpload.BulkUploadWithMetaDataRequest request)
{
    StringBuilder Success = new StringBuilder();
    CSVUploadResponse response = new CSVUploadResponse();

    try
    {
        if (request == null)
        {
            response.ReturnMessage = "Unable To process.Please try again.";
            return response;
        }

        string BulkUploadWithMetaDataServiceFilePath = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BulkUploadWithMetaDataServiceFilePath"]);

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(BulkUploadWithMetaDataServiceFilePath))
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(BulkUploadWithMetaDataServiceFilePath);

            System.IO.FileInfo fi = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(file => file.Name).ToArray().Where(file => file.Extension.ToLower() == ".json").ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

            if (fi == null)
            {
                System.IO.File.Create(BulkUploadWithMetaDataServiceFilePath + "\\Records.json").Close();
                fi = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(file => file.Name).ToArray().Where(file => file.Extension.ToLower() == ".json").ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
            }

            string directoryName = string.Empty;

            DateTime dateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
            string formattedDate = dateTimeNow.ToString("ddMMyyyy");
            string directoryNameWithoutNumber = BulkUploadWithMetaDataServiceFilePath + "\\" + Convert.ToString(request.LoggedInUserId) + "_" + formattedDate;
            int directoryCount = 1;
            directoryName = directoryNameWithoutNumber + "_" + Convert.ToString(directoryCount);

            while (Directory.Exists(directoryName))
            {
                directoryCount++;
                directoryName = directoryNameWithoutNumber + "_" + Convert.ToString(directoryCount);
            }

            Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);

            //foreach (BusinessEntities.Request.BulkUpload.FileUploadItem data in request.FileUploadItemList)
            //{
            //    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(directoryName + "\\" + data.FileName, data.FileContent);
            //}//Will delete this

            string jsonText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName);
            List<BusinessEntities.Response.BulkUpload.BulkUploadResponse> BulkUploadResponseList =
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BusinessEntities.Response.BulkUpload.BulkUploadResponse>>(jsonText);

            if (BulkUploadResponseList == null)
            {
                BulkUploadResponseList = new List<BusinessEntities.Response.BulkUpload.BulkUploadResponse>();
            }

            var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            BusinessEntities.Response.BulkUpload.BulkUploadResponse BulkUploadResponse = new BusinessEntities.Response.BulkUpload.BulkUploadResponse()
            {
                Id = guid,
                DocTypeId = request.DocTypeId,
                ProcessId = request.ProcessId,
                ClassificationLevel = request.ClassificationLevel,
                Priority = request.Priority,
                FolderId = request.FolderId,
                TreatFileNameAsDocumentNumber = request.TreatFileNameAsDocumentNumber,
                IsCompleted = "N",
                LoggedInUserId = request.LoggedInUserId,
                MetaDataDateFormat = request.MetaDataDateFormat,
                Progress = 0,
                RequestedOn = DateTime.Now,
                TotalRecords = request.FileUploadItemList.Count(),
                DirectoryName = directoryName,
                FileName = Path.GetFileName(directoryName)
            };

            BulkUploadResponseList.Add(BulkUploadResponse);

            string updatedJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(BulkUploadResponseList, Formatting.Indented);

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fi.FullName, updatedJson);
            response.Ref1 = guid;

            Success.Append("Your file is now in queue for processing!");

            response.ReturnMessage = Convert.ToString(Success);

            return response;
        }
        else
        {
            Success.Append("Folder structure not configured as per defined in configuration. Please contact DocPro Administrator.");
            response.ReturnMessage = Convert.ToString(Success);
            return response;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        response.ReturnMessage = ex.Message;
    }

    return response;
}

[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[Filters.AuthorizeLoginApi()]
[Route("api/BulkUpload/BulkUpload/UpdateFileChunkBulkUploadWithMetaDataJSON")]
public SPResponse UpdateFileChunkBulkUploadWithMetaDataJSON([FromBody] DocPro.DMS.BusinessEntities.Request.BulkUpload.BulkUploadWithMetaDataRequest request)
{
    SPResponse response = new SPResponse();

    if (request == null)
    {
        response.ReturnMessage = "Unable To process.Please try again.";
        return response;
    }

    string BulkUploadWithMetaDataServiceFilePath = Convert.ToString(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BulkUploadWithMetaDataServiceFilePath"]);

    if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(BulkUploadWithMetaDataServiceFilePath))
    {
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(BulkUploadWithMetaDataServiceFilePath);

        System.IO.FileInfo fi = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(file => file.Name).ToArray().Where(file => file.Extension.ToLower() == ".json").ToArray().FirstOrDefault();

        if (fi == null)
        {
            System.IO.File.Create(BulkUploadWithMetaDataServiceFilePath + "\\Records.json").Close();
            fi = di.GetFiles().OrderBy(file => file.Name).ToArray().Where(file => file.Extension.ToLower() == ".json").ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
        }

        //var jsonFile = Path.Combine(fi.DirectoryName, fi.FullName);
        DirectoryInfo jdi = new DirectoryInfo(fi.DirectoryName);
        FileInfo[] jFile = jdi.GetFiles("Records.json");

        foreach (FileInfo json in jFile)
        {
            string jsonFileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(json.FullName);
            var jsonConfig = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BusinessEntities.Response.BulkUpload.BulkUploadResponse>>(jsonFileText);
            foreach (var data in jsonConfig)
            {
                if (data.Id == request.Id)
                {
                    data.FileContent = AppendData(data.FileContent, request.FileUploadItemList[0].FileContent);

                    if (request.FileUploadItemList[0].ChunkUploaded)
                    {
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(data.DirectoryName + "\\" + request.FileUploadItemList[0].FileName, data.FileContent);
                        data.FileContent = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

            //foreach (BusinessEntities.Request.BulkUpload.FileUploadItem data in request.FileUploadItemList)
            //{
            //    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(directoryName + "\\" + data.FileName, data.FileContent);
            //}
            response.ReturnMessage = "Chunk Uploaded";
        response.ReturnStatus = "0";
    }

    return response;
}

What I am doing is appending a chunk in JSON after all the chunks got appended I am storing the file in my hard drive.
What is wrong here?
